# c3p0 gerando muitas conexões

Tags: java, jetty, pooling, c3p0

Codigo que obtém a conexão

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/oracledb");
            Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            return connection;
```

Configuracao web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/oracledb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Configuração do c3p0 no jetty

```
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="myds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/oracledb</Arg>
    <Arg>

         <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"> 
            <Set name="driverClass">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</Set> 
            <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@SRVODA-SCAN.CAIRUNET.AD.BR:1521/WINTP</Set> 
            <Set name="user">x</Set> 
            <Set name="password">x</Set> 
            <Set name="maxPoolSize">20</Set>
            <Set name="minPoolSize">5</Set>
            <Set name="acquireIncrement">5</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">45</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">30</Set>
            <Set name="preferredTestQuery">select sysdate from dual</Set>

        </New> 

    </Arg>
</New>
```

Fecha a conexao

```
public static boolean closeConnection(Connection connection) {

    if(connection != null) {
        try {
            if(!connection.isClosed()) {
                connection.close();
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Versões:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

O jetty é a versão para eclipse 8x

Agora o problema, toda vez ao pegar um conexão, o log de console do eclipse está registrando uma inicialização do pool, e isso gera uma lentidão ao conectar com o banco de dados, uma lentidão significativa
(obs, o log é muito maior que isso, pra não ficar muito grande, peguei só um pedaço do log)

```
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 2ukwbk9rlq3x1yrxl5ji|591f989e, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 2ukwbk9rlq3x1yrxl5ji|591f989e, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@SRVODA-SCAN.CAIRUNET.AD.BR:1521/WINTP, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 45, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 30, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> select sysdate from dual, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
out 24, 2017 8:13:21 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
ADVERTÊNCIA: Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 5. Using 5 as start.
out 24, 2017 8:13:22 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource 
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 2ukwbk9rlq3x1yrxl5ji|591f989e, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 2ukwbk9rlq3x1yrxl5ji|591f989e, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@SRVODA-SCAN.CAIRUNET.AD.BR:1521/WINTP, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 45, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 30, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> select sysdate from dual, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
out 24, 2017 8:13:22 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
ADVERTÊNCIA: Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 5. Using 5 as start.
out 24, 2017 8:13:22 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource 
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 2ukwbk9rlq3x1yrxl5ji|591f989e, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 2ukwbk9rlq3x1yrxl5ji|591f989e, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@SRVODA-SCAN.CAIRUNET.AD.BR:1521/WINTP, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 45, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 30, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> select sysdate from dual, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
out 24, 2017 8:13:22 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
ADVERTÊNCIA: Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 5. Using 5 as start.
```

La no oracle, com uma pessoa usando, e realizando operação básica, tem 1500 sessoes INACTIVE que não são descartadas

[image: sessoes no BD]

O que posso estar fazendo de errado aqui? Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que a sua configuração cria uma `DataSource` c3p0 cada vez que começa, mas não chama o `close()` nesse mesmo `DataSource` quando reinicia. Com o passar do tempo, acaba por lançar vários `DataSource`s e os "vazar" em cada vez reinicia.

Precisa de configurar o Jetty (não tenho certeza de como) para chamar o `close()` sobre o `DataSource` c3p0 de cada vez que a aplicação fecha e reinicia.

---

Resposta original (em inglês):

> I'm sorry to respond in English, but I don't know Portuguese!
>
> It looks like your configuration creates a c3p0 DataSource each time it starts, but does not call close() on the DataSource on hot redeploy. Over time, you start up lots of DataSources, and then "leak" them with each restart. You need to configure Jetty (I'm not sure how) to call close() on the c3p0 DataSource each time the application shuts down and restarts.

Comment: Isto é uma comunidade portuguesa, e por esse motivo haverão vários usuários que não sabem falar inglês o que faz com que a sua resposta não tenha utilidade prática | This is a portuguese community, and for that reason some if not many of its users will not be able to speak english, which makes your answer not useful.

Comment: sorry! i'm the author of the c3p0 library, but i don't speak Portuguese. (i wish i did!) english is the best i can do.

Comment: Considering that your post isn't very big, i'm willing to translate it for you, if you want

Comment: sure, that'd be great!

Comment: ......obrigado!

Comment: @Isac Muito obrigado pela tradução. Eu adicionei a versão original, acho interessante mantê-la.

Comment: @LINQ Sim, agradeço, estive para fazer isso e acabei por não fazer, mas acho que realmente fica melhor.

Comment: @SteveWaldman, Obrigado por responder a pergunta, por hora eu optei por usar o tomcat pra gerenciar minhas conexões, pois preciso andar com o projeto, mas sua sugestão é provavelmente a causa do erro e irei pesquisa a respeito de como fazer isso no jetty. || Thanks for answering the question, for the time being I opted to use tomcat to manage my connections as I need to walk with the project, but your suggestion is probably the cause of the error and I will research on how to do this in jetty.

Isac e LINQ Obrigado por traduzir